# JS - If multiple conditions can be true at the same time, which one runs?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

If multiple if-statements can be true at the same time, how does JS determine which one to run? In the example below, I know "Cool, now I have a lot of nachos to myself." will get returned, but I just wonder how that is determined? What if instead of `friendsAtYourParty === 0` it would be `friendsAtYourParty < 3` ("Cool, now I have a lot of nachos to myself." would get returned again, but why?). I was thinking maybe the one that is more specific/closer to the value "wins"?

```
if (friendsAtYourParty === 0) {
  console.log("Cool, now I have a lot of nachos to myself.");
} else if (friendsAtYourParty < 4) {
  console.log("Perfect amount to play some Mario Kart.");
} else {
  console.log("Wooooo turn on the dance music!");
}
```

Comment: The first one that matches. You ARE after all using `if/else` - the `else` part will *only* be executed when the `if` part isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an `if/else` chain *only* the first `if` condition that matches would be executed. After all, that's how `if/else` works:

```
if (condition) {
  //only executed when condition is true
} else {
  //only executed when condition is false 
}
```

The `else` part will NOT execute when the condition is `true`. Nothing changes when you have more than one `if/else`:

```
if (condition1) {
  //only executed when condition1 is true
} else if (condition2) {
  //only executed when condition2 is true and condition1 is false
} else {
 //only executed when both condition1 and condition2 are false
}
```

An `if/else` chain describes the following logic flow, hence why it will always be evaluated predictably:

[image: Flowchart describing the if/else chain]

Answer (score 0):

Basically first true condition runs. It happens because JS code gets run and executed line by line. When JS engine sees if statement and the condition is false it continues to read the code. When it sees the condition that is true it executes the statement declared after the condition and then removes if statement from a callstack. In other words: It is not going to read other conditions after it saw true. It will ignore them

Comment: "*It happens because JS code gets run and executed line by line.*" yet the *same* mechanism is present in Java, C, C++, PHP, Python, Ruby, and any other language that I know of, both compiled and interpreted. So no, this isn't the reason. This is the only way to follow the instructions you give the computer.

Answer (score 0):

> Lets consider friendsAtYourParty value is 8

1. if (friendsAtYourParty === 0) {     **// 8 == 0 returns false so it skips this block**
2. console.log("Cool, now I have a lot of nachos to myself.");
3. } else if (friendsAtYourParty < 4) { **// 8 < 4 returns false so it skips this block**
4. console.log("Perfect amount to play some Mario Kart.");
5. } else {   **// there is no condition in else , so if all conditions fail in above blocks it will execute this**
6. console.log("Wooooo turn on the dance music!");
7. }

> Lets consider another scenario where friendsAtYourParty is 0

1. if (friendsAtYourParty === 0) {     **// 0 == 0 returns true so it runs this block and gets out of if else chain and ignores all blocks in if else chain**
2. console.log("Cool, now I have a lot of nachos to myself.");
3. } else if (friendsAtYourParty < 4) { **// 0 < 4 returns true but its ignored**
4. console.log("Perfect amount to play some Mario Kart.");
5. } else {   **// this is also ignored**
6. console.log("Wooooo turn on the dance music!");
7. }

> Press Ctrl+shift+i to open dev tools  , run the following snippet and 
>   press f19 to go step by step to understand the flow.

```js
debugger
var friendsAtYourParty=8;
if (friendsAtYourParty === 0) {
  console.log("Cool, now I have a lot of nachos to myself.");
} else if (friendsAtYourParty < 4) {
  console.log("Perfect amount to play some Mario Kart.");
} else {
  console.log("Wooooo turn on the dance music!");
}
friendsAtYourParty=0;
if (friendsAtYourParty === 0) {
  console.log("Cool, now I have a lot of nachos to myself.");
} else if (friendsAtYourParty < 4) {
  console.log("Perfect amount to play some Mario Kart.");
} else {
  console.log("Wooooo turn on the dance music!");
}
```